# PHP- Tabela com repetições em laços utilizando array multidimensional

Tags: php, array, loop, table

Olá, preciso fazer uma tabela como a da imagem [image: tabela exemplo] mas utilizando esse array:

```
$teste = array();
$teste[0]['produtos']['nome'] = "Produto 1";
$teste[0]['produtos']['descricao'] = "Descrição do produto 1";
$teste[0]['produtos']['valor'] = 50;
$teste[0]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 1";
$teste[0]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 2";
$teste[0]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 3";
$teste[1]['produtos']['nome'] = "Produto 2";
$teste[1]['produtos']['descricao'] = "Descrição do produto 2";
$teste[1]['produtos']['valor'] = 75;
$teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 1";
$teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 2";
$teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 3";
$teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 4";
$teste[2]['produtos']['nome'] = "Produto 3";
$teste[2]['produtos']['descricao'] = "Descrição do produto 3";
$teste[2]['produtos']['valor'] = 100;
$teste[2]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 1";
$teste[2]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 2";
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso? Estou tentando usar o `foreach`, mas o conceito ainda é novo para mim e estou com dificuldade em entender.

E depois de fazer isso ainda tenho que montar a mesma tabela, mas invertendo a ordenação usando uma função de ordenação do PHP.

Comment: Para montar a tabela invertendo a ordenação utilize a função para *Array* [arsort](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.arsort.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma direta de fazer isso seria com 2 `for` um para cada produto e outro para as opções.

Algo como:

```
//neste for percorre os produtos, e utiliza count para saber quantos tem
for ($i = 0; $i < count($teste); ++$i){ 
    //usar o $teste[$i]['produtos']['nome'];
    //usar a $teste[$i]['produtos']['descricao'];
    //usar o $teste[$i]['produtos']['valor'];

    //foreach aqui percorre as várias opções
    foreach ($teste[$i]['produtos']['opcionais'] as $opcoes){
        //usar o $opcoes
    }
}
```

Agora basta construir o html necessário á medida que navega nos vários elementos.

Um exemplo dessa construção seria assim:

```
<?php

$teste = array();
$teste[0]['produtos']['nome'] = "Produto 1";
$teste[0]['produtos']['descricao'] = "Descrição do produto 1";
$teste[0]['produtos']['valor'] = 50;
$teste[0]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 1";
$teste[0]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 2";
$teste[0]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 3";
$teste[1]['produtos']['nome'] = "Produto 2";
$teste[1]['produtos']['descricao'] = "Descrição do produto 2";
$teste[1]['produtos']['valor'] = 75;
$teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 1";
$teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 2";
$teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 3";
$teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 4";
$teste[2]['produtos']['nome'] = "Produto 3";
$teste[2]['produtos']['descricao'] = "Descrição do produto 3";
$teste[2]['produtos']['valor'] = 100;
$teste[2]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 1";
$teste[2]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 2";

?>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Produto</th>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
        <th>Opções</th>
    </tr>
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < count($teste); ++$i){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $teste[$i]['produtos']['nome'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $teste[$i]['produtos']['descricao'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $teste[$i]['produtos']['valor'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    //opções
    foreach ($teste[$i]['produtos']['opcionais'] as $opcoes){
        echo "$opcoes<br/>";
    }

    echo "</td></tr>";
}

?>
</table>
```

Comment: Nossa agora que vi que você também respondeu. Sua resposta ficou parecida com a minha, a unica coisa q nesse caso dela, não é necessario um for com contador. Pq ela ta usando sequencia numeral na chave do array, e o foreach ja segue essa sequencia sem precisar fazer a contagem.

Comment: Mas é bom ela ver esse método também, dependendo do caso q ela tiver no futuro também pode ser útil

Comment: @FernandoVR Sim eu sei, foi para mostrar que dá para fazer das duas maneiras. Tanto dava com `2` `for` como com 2 `foreach` como intercalado como eu fiz.

Comment: Ahh ok entendi a sua intenção agora ^^

Comment: @FernandoVR E talvez até no primeiro `for` seja mais intuitivo fazer pelos indices uma vez que é numérico sequencial, apesar de ser mais direto com `foreach` como você fez

Comment: É verdade, eu raramente utilizo o for com arrays, ja fico no automático fazendo tudo direto pelo foreach. Tudo é relativo tbm neh, rsrs. Eu ja uso o for quando preciso de duas contagens, e arrays multidimensionais mais complicados.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa iniciar um array vazio nesse seu caso quando vc inicia um array usando colchetes, o PHP ja entende que se trata de um array, então pode ignorar a linha `$teste = array();`.

Você pode usar um foreach dentro do outro. um para listar a primeira camada, e outro para listar a segunda camada com opções.

Tente dessa forma:

```
    <?php
        $teste[0]['produtos']['nome'] = "Produto 1";
        $teste[0]['produtos']['descricao'] = "Descrição do produto 1";
        $teste[0]['produtos']['valor'] = 50;
        $teste[0]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 1";
        $teste[0]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 2";
        $teste[0]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 3";
        $teste[1]['produtos']['nome'] = "Produto 2";
        $teste[1]['produtos']['descricao'] = "Descrição do produto 2";
        $teste[1]['produtos']['valor'] = 75;
        $teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 1";
        $teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 2";
        $teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 3";
        $teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 4";
        $teste[2]['produtos']['nome'] = "Produto 3";
        $teste[2]['produtos']['descricao'] = "Descrição do produto 3";
        $teste[2]['produtos']['valor'] = 100;
        $teste[2]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 1";
        $teste[2]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 2";


        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr><th>Nome</th><th>Descrição</th><th>Valor</th><th>Opcionais</th></tr>';

        foreach($teste as $val) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo "<td valign=\"top\">{$val['produtos']['nome']}</td>";
            echo "<td valign=\"top\">{$val['produtos']['descricao']}</td>";
            echo "<td valign=\"top\">{$val['produtos']['valor']}</td>";
            echo "<td>";

               foreach($val['produtos']['opcionais'] as $itemopcional) {
                   echo "- {$itemopcional}</br>";
               }

            echo "</td>";
            echo '</tr>';
        }

        echo '</table>';
 ?>
```

E para ordenação vc pode verificar a documentação do php para ordenações de Arrays:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/array.sorting.php

Como não sei o tipo de ordenação que deseja fazer, então coloquei só o link acima. Mas você pode fazer depois outra nova pergunta sobre ordenação caso tenha alguma dificuldade.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode detectar se é um array e alterar o comportamento dele, basicamente desta forma:

```
<table style="width:100%">
<?php
foreach($teste as $linha){
    echo '<tr>';

    foreach($linha['produtos'] as $coluna){        
        echo '<td>';

        if(is_array($coluna)){            
            foreach($coluna as $valor){
                echo '<li>';
                echo $valor;
                echo '</li>';
            }            
        }else{        
            echo $coluna;
        }

        echo '</td>';        
    }  

    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Lógico que há outras formas de fazer, mas assim acredito que fique mais claro como ele funciona.

Ele irá em cada linha criar um `td` e então mostrar os valores, porém se for um `array` ele irá criar uns `li` para cada um. Se quiser uma versão mais compacta poderia utilizar:

```
<?php
$teste = array();
$teste[0]['produtos']['nome'] = "Produto 1";
$teste[0]['produtos']['descricao'] = "Descrição do produto 1";
$teste[0]['produtos']['valor'] = 50;
$teste[0]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 1";
$teste[0]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 2";
$teste[0]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 3";
$teste[1]['produtos']['nome'] = "Produto 2";
$teste[1]['produtos']['descricao'] = "Descrição do produto 2";
$teste[1]['produtos']['valor'] = 75;
$teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 1";
$teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 2";
$teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 3";
$teste[1]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 4";
$teste[2]['produtos']['nome'] = "Produto 3";
$teste[2]['produtos']['descricao'] = "Descrição do produto 3";
$teste[2]['produtos']['valor'] = 100;
$teste[2]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 1";
$teste[2]['produtos']['opcionais'][] = "Opcional 2";
?>
<table style="width:100%">
<?php
foreach($teste as $linha){
    echo '<tr>';

    foreach($linha['produtos'] as $valor){       
        if(is_array($valor)){            
            $valor = '<li>'.implode($valor, '</li><li>').'</li>';
        }

        echo '<td>' . $valor . '</td>';
    }  

    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

O `implode` fará implicitamente o mesmo que o loop faria.